# How to change flutter webview setState() method

Tags: flutter, webview

I am trying to implement webView in my flutter apps. It's working nicely with CircularProgressIndicator but i cant hide the loading bar. Here is my webview dart file:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class MyWebView extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String selectedUrl;

  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
  Completer<WebViewController>();

  MyWebView({
    @required this.title,
    @required this.selectedUrl,
  });

 bool isLoading = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            new WebView(
              initialUrl: selectedUrl,
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                _controller.complete(webViewController);
              },
              onPageFinished: (finish) {
                setState(() {
                  isLoading = false;
                });
              },
            ),
            isLoading ? Center( child: CircularProgressIndicator()) : Container(),
          ],
        ),
    );
  }
```

It just shows Error: The method 'setState' isn't defined for the class 'MyWebView'. Can anybody suggest me on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

@Enayet, you are using `setState` in `StatelessWidget`. You can only do that in `StatefulWidget`. You need to change your widget class to below if you want to use `setState`,

```
class MyWebView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final String selectedUrl;

  const MyWebView({Key key, @required this.title, @required this.selectedUrl}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyWebViewState createState() => MyWebViewState();
}

class MyWebViewState extends State<MyWebView> {
....
```

Learn more about `StatefulWidget` here - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html